# Timber/TWIG for Wordpress - Questions about some basics

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

For instance in the **Timber Documentation** we have lots of examples like the following:

```
{% for item in menu.items %}

{{ post.author.name }}
```

Now the "**item**" and the "**menu**" etc. are all predefined, and nowhere defined by a user in the files (otherwise by my understanding Timber and TWIG would not make much sense).

What I do not understand is where I can find out a list these. In the Docs of Timber, there are a bunch of examples, then when I compare them to the Timber Starter Theme for Wordpress, I see a bunch of them, which aren't even mentioned in the documentations.

1. **Where do I find a list of all available items?**
2. **What is the logic behind these items?**

Comment: To view all accessible variables u could do something like e.g. `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}`

Comment: @DarkBee So how come there is no list of prebuild items?
I don't get how I should learn to use Timber. How do I get a hang of it, do you have a few links? If you tell me, after reading the entire Docs I'd get it, I'm glad to do that.
The problem for me is, I don't even know how what I am looking for is called. Nowhere is mentioned, if I have to make all of these "items" myself, or if they are all prebuilt or whatever. I actually have no idea what is going on, and what I have to study.

Comment: I'm not actually using `timber` myself, i'm just using `twig` actually but it seems the new documentation can be found over [here](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/)

Comment: @DarkBee Those are the ones I was working with.
My issue is that I can't just go and guess variables to output and hope for the best.
Is there any chance you could help me with some questions a bit more in detail? I know this is dumb to ask for, however there isn't enough material on the web to help me - it's mainly this basic questions about the Variables etc.

I'm trying to get them answered for more than a week now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t feel dumb, because you’re not! We’ve all been there. I had the same questions, when I started out with Timber. We’re trying to improve the documentation constantly, so questions like these help us to find out what we can do better .

Whenever you see a variable in Twig, it can actually come from a couple of different places:

### Variables from the global context

There’s a filter that most of us use to make a variable globally available whenever you set up your context through `Timber::get_context()`. When you see `{% for item in menu.items %}`, then it’s probably from the section of the docs about [«Setting up a menu globally»](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/menus/#setting-up-a-menu-globally). I have to admit that we explain the filter through this example only, which is not ideal. But we’re changing this. In the next version of Timber, we try to [explain the global context better](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/2.x/docs/guides/context.md#global-context) (make sure to only read the section about the global context, because the part about «Template Contexts» describes functionality that is not available yet.)

### Variables from the template

Consider the following example:

```
$context         = Timber::get_context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();

Timber::render( 'single.twig', $context );
```

Here you set up your context through `Timber::get_context()`. When you use `Timber::get_context()`, you’ll get a bunch of variables that make sense globally, but not for every template.

The `$context` variable is an array, holding all the variables you want to pass to your Twig template, in this case **single.twig**. When can add our own variables, like in the example above, where we add `post` that hold a `Timber\Post` object of the currently displayed post.

### Variables from Timber’s classes

In the template, when you see `{{ post.author.name }}`, then `author` can be different things:

- A property of the `Timber\Post` object that holds a value. These are all the variables that you’d see when you do `{{ dump(post) }}`.
- A method of the `Timber\Post` object, that will be excecuted. This might be confusing at first, because in PHP, you always need to add braces to call a function, but in Twig, you don’t need to. When you call `$post->author()` in PHP, you would use `post.author` in Twig. To see a list of all the methods that are available for `Timber\Post`, you need to look into the Reference section for [`Timber\Post` in the docs](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#methods).

So if you would write the example `{{ post.author.name }}` in PHP, it would look like this:

```
$post->author()->name()
```

So [`author`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#author) is a method of `Timber\Post`, which returns a `Timber\User` object. The `Timber\User` object has a method called [`name`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-user/#name), which returns «the human-friendly name of the user».

But! When you just look at `{{ post.author.name }}`, it could also be a multi-dimensional array that you defined yourself:

```
$context['post'] = array(
    'author' => array(
        'name' => 'Tom Riddle',
     ),
);
```

You wouldn’t know that just from looking at it in Twig.

### Variables from the Twig syntax

When you see `{% for item in menu.items %}`, then you’re looping over the variable `menu.items`. The variable `menu` probably comes from the global context (a `Timber\Menu` object), and [`items`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-menu/#properties) is a property of this object. The `item` variable is a new variable that is created to access the current loop item in the [for loop](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html). In this example, it’s the current menu item. You can choose any name for `item` you want.

### Variables from includes

You can pass down a variable in Twig through the [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) statement. For example, if you defined `post` through your template file and wanted to use a different name in the template that you include, you could use it like this:

```
{% include 'teaser.twig' with { teaser: post } %}
```

---

Coming back to your specific questions:

> 1. Where do I find a list of all available items?
> 2. What is the logic behind these items?

I’m afraid there isn’t a definitive list, because what a variable is can be very dynamic. It’s mostly a combination of the global context, variables you set from the template, methods and properties from [Timber’s classes](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/) as well as variables you define yourself in Twig.

If you have more question, add the to this answer as comments and I can update this answer accordingly.